# Split box in two

Tags: subfloats, bounding-box

I need to create a figure with two small figures; I want it to be a box that is split into two, with a syntax tree located in each side. The MWE below shows what I'm trying and failing with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{ textcomp }
\newcommand\TR[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{default}
            \label{fig:figure1}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{default}
            \label{fig:figure2}
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This code creates two separate boxes, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a tabular environment with lines such a splitted box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{ textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\TR[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{tabular}{|*2{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5\linewidth}|}}
            \hline
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            & \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
            \end{tikzpicture}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: trees in a table]

If you need a caption for each tree, you could use the [`subcaption`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) package.

Alternatively, you could use a split rectangular node with TikZ.

Answer (score 6):

You could modify the space you are putting between the two boxes so that the borders overlap. By default the width of a rule is `.4pt`. So you would get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{ textcomp }
\newcommand\TR[1]{\textlangle#1\textrangle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{default}
            \label{fig:figure1}
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \hspace{-.4pt}%
    \fbox{
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
                \Tree [ .NP [ .vP[DE] { } [ .v' v\\dai [ .VP { } [ .V' V\\\TR{dai} yanjing ] ] ] ] NP\\nanhai ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{default}
            \label{fig:figure2}
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Trees in split box]

Comment: I've heard that fighting LaTex with negative space is bad, but I like not having to load a separate package to have captions.

Comment: @NateGlenn: Well, you are already using TikZ, so you could just use that to draw a box like Stefan suggests. Although that is not as straightforward as it seems. Leaving captioning + labelling working will (I believe) require a separate tikz picture overlay. Assuming you still don't want extra packages.